# How to change html body tag attribute in gwt/gxt project

Tags: html, gwt, gxt

I'm building a gxt project.
I want to add a configuration of locale that will come from a properties file.
for example:

```
user.direction=rtl
```

I want to change the body tag of the html file of the project, according to this configuration:

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

is there a way to do it throw the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RootPanel.getBodyElement().setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
```

Works on GWT 2.4.0 for older version I'm not sure.